# Upload file from php doesn't work using a varaible in the path but works if i added a value

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file form my c# program to php server the problem is that when i sent the path as a  variable from c# to the php file ($gradephp) it uploads the file to files folders (even that he reads the variable value using echo statement) but if I set the variable value($gardephp="4") in the php file it uploads correctly

Here is my code

```
<?php
    $servername="******";
    $server_username="***";
    $server_Password="****";
    $dbName="public";
    $gradephp=$_POST["gradephp"];
    $qphp=$_POST["qidphp"];

    $uploads_dir = "files/".$gradephp."/";
    echo $uploads_dir;

    if (file_exists($_FILES)) {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
        $name = $_FILES["file"]["name"].$qphp;
        echo $gradephp.$qphp;
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $uploads_dir.$name);
        echo "ok";
    }
?>
```

I also tried this but the same problem occurs:

```
<?php
    $servername="******";
    $server_username="***";
    $server_Password="****";
    $dbName="public";
    $gradephp=$_POST["gradephp"];
    $qphp=$_POST["qidphp"];
    $x=$gradephp;
    echo $x;
    if ($x == "1") {
        $uploads_dir = "files/1/";
    }
    else if ($x == "2") {
        $uploads_dir = "files/2/";
    }
    else if ($x == "3") {
        $uploads_dir = "files/3/";
    }
    else if ($x == "4") {
        $uploads_dir = "files/4/";
    }
    else if ($x == "5") {
        $uploads_dir = "files/5/";
    }
    else if ($x == "6") {
        $uploads_dir = "files/6/";
    }
    else {
        echo "notfound";
    }
    echo $uploads_dir;
    if (file_exists($_FILES)) {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
        $name = $_FILES["file"]["name"].$qphp;
        echo $gradephp.$qphp;
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $uploads_dir.$name);
        echo "ok";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It uses [`POST`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)

```
$gradephp=$_POST["gradephp"];`
```

You can't set it via the URL but would have to make a POST request using a form. Basically that's the reason why `POST` is usually used: So the user can't see/manipulate the value in the URL.

Assuming you are using a [`UnityWebRequest.Post`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest-SendingForm.html) you would add the parameter to e.g. `MultiPartFormSection` like

```
List<IMultipartFormSection> formData = new List<IMultipartFormSection>();
formData.Add(new MultipartFormDataSection("gradephp=4"));
formData.Add(new MultipartFormFileSection("my file data", "myfile.txt"));

using (var www = UnityWebRequest.Post("http://some.host.url", formData);
{
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();
}
```

---

If however you **want** to be able to set it via the URL like in your case e.g.

```
http://some.host.url?gradephp=4
```

rather use [`GET`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.get.php) instead:

```
$gradephp=$_GET["gradephp"];
```

Comment: I am already using a form to post the variables 
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm ();
    form.AddField ("imagephp",imagew+qidw);
form.AddField ("gradephp","4");
 if (imagew != "lo235lo" ) {
  System.Net.WebClient Client = new System.Net.WebClient ();
byte[] result = Client.UploadFile (url + "/add.php", "POST",
  @imagew );
 string s = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString (result, 0, result.Length);   
  }
  WW www = new WWW (url+"/add.php",form);
    while (www.isDone != true) {
                }
                    yield return www.text;
                    
    }

Comment: What I see there is two different calls: one using `Client.UploadFile` without passing the form data but only the file content. And another one using `WWW` passing only the form data but not the file content ....

Comment: i want to post the variable and a file , is there is another way.
Thanks for your reply